# Do instance variables within helper methods persist between each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting into developing Ruby on Rails apps and found a useful tutorial (Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5)) by Michael Hartl.
I'm in chapter 8 right now, where we are developing a bare, simple login/logout functionality from the ground up.

In the tutorial, a helper module is created to check if a user is logged in already. This is called on each request within the header.html.erb partial, in order to determine which links to show in the header.

```
module SessionsHelper

  #Logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
      !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

Anyway, the author describes this line is used to prevent having to query the database for the user record each time a request is made (only for the first request if the user is logged on)

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
```

This makes sense to me, but I notice in the server's console, after each request, the database is still being queried for the user's record as @current_user is always reset to nil.
So my question is, is this normal? The @current_user variable isn't persisting between requests so I feel like something is wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Great question. Especially checking the console to see what it's reporting. That'll prevent a ton of future pain and debugging trouble when working with rails! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it exactly right and getting the proper results!

> author describes this line is used to prevent having to query the database for the user record each time a request is made

Check the wording on this. What the author is likely saying is the database query is only made once **per request** no matter how many times the `current_user` method is called.

The pattern you're seeing is called [memoization](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/) and is a shorthand form of the following:

```
  def current_user
    if @current_user.nil?
      @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
    @current_user
  end
```

You actually don't want this variable to persist between requests because that means if a new user loaded the page, they'd get the old user's `User` object. Which is exactly what you don't want!

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks for the quick answer. Your second point was also something I was wondering about. Was getting hung up on what I was reading in the tutorial so figured I should ask for help